# Aligning text input in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development, and am trying to complete a bootleg copy of the google homepage, however for some reason the search bar I'm working on won't align to the center.

I've gone through the solutions at the bottom of the page ([here](http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/html-css?ref=lnav)), and searched for a solution here however nothing seems to work.

Here's a link to [jsfiddle of the files](https://jsfiddle.net/nmw18g9t/2/) as well as a copy of the code below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/googlelogo.png" alt="Google Logo">
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
form input {
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 50%:
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with you css part.
You have added a colon instead of semicolon.Apart from that everything looks good to me
Change this

```css
form input {
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 50%:
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

to

```css
form input {
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now it will work

Comment: Oh jeez, that explains it. Thanks so much, I spent way to long looking for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to use `position:absolute` simply use `text align`.**

```css
body {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.logo {
 margin-top: 50px;
    /* width: 125px; */
    /* top: 40%; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    text-align: center;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
form input {
 border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 53%; */
    /*left: 50%: transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<title>Google</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.bd/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo">
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</body>
```